# How to listen key and mouse event at a time in SWT(Shift+ Left MouseUp)?

Tags: java, swt

I want to capture Shift+Left Mouse Up event in SWT. I just want to print some sample message only **while holding shift key down and releasing the left mouse button**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for `SWT.MouseUp` and compare the `Event.stateMask` to `SWT.SHIFT`, then compare `Event.button` to `1`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    text.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            if ((e.stateMask & SWT.SHIFT) != 0 && e.button == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("shift pressed and left mouse clicked");
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    shell.layout(true, true);

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Baz for ur suggestion and the answer. But, you misunderstood my question. I asked for left "mouse button up", not for left Arrow key up.

Comment: Your answer is working fine for left arrow. Please help in detecting Shift + Left mouse up event only. It should differentiate left and right mouse clicks.

Comment: @varma Ok, updated the answer. It will now check for shift and left mouse button.